# Using induction, how to find all positive number $n$ such that $5^{n} > n!$?

Tags: induction, contest-math

Using induction, how to find all positive number $n$ such that 
$$ 5^{n} > n!$$

---

**Attempt:**

I found this problem in the Induction topic in an education material.

I know starting that $n=12$ then $5^{n} < n!$. Is it because that we have to prove that for $n \ge 12$ then $5^{n} < n!$ by induction...? Hence the answer is $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11$.

Or is there another way using induction.

Comment: Hint: If $n\geq12$ and $5^n<n!$ then $5^{n+1}=5^n\cdot 5<n!\cdot(n+1)=(n+1)!$

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, $5^n > n!$ only if $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$. Induction will show that $5^n < n!$ with $n=12$ as your base step.

Base Case:

If $n=12$, then $5^{12}<(12)!$.

Induction Hypothesis:

Assume that $5^n < n!$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ where $n\ge 12$.

Induction Step:

We need to show that $5^{n+1} < (n+1)!$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ where $n\ge 12$. Starting from the LHS

\begin{align}5^{n+1}&=5^n5 \\&<n!\cdot 5 \\&< n!\cdot n \\&< n!\cdot (n+1)
\\&=(n+1)!\end{align}

Therefore, this allows us to conclude that

1. $5^n > n!$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$.
2. $5^n < n!$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $n\ge 12$.

Comment: Adding the portion that begins "You could also use induction to show that $5^n > n!$..." needlessly confuses the issue.  Your answer would be better without it.